# What does "strobe" mean in the context of semiconductors?

Tags: digital-logic, semiconductors, jargon

I was reading the data sheet for SN7425, and it calls the semiconductor a "Dual 4-Input NOR Gates With Strobe"
What does it mean by "Strobe"? Does it affect input/output?

https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn7425.pdf?ts=1697433537010&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fen.wikipedia.org%252F

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means that the output is valid only when the strobe signal is enabled. In the case of the SN74/5425 the G input is the strobe pin.  Per the logic chart the outputs are only valid when G is High. (Except for the obvious 0000 input which is a High output either way.)

This could be utilized for example if you had 4 signals that were not synchronized in time. You could have a separate signal that signifies when the inputs are known to be in sync, you then "Strobe" the gates and read the valid output.

Also note that the old scanned datasheet is a bit difficult to read. Here is a newer version of the [7425 datasheet](https://www.nteinc.com/specs/7400to7499/pdf/nte7425.pdf).

A few vendors that still sell this part include simplified logic gate symbols that include the strobe input. In this form it may be easier for some to understand the basic gate function.
[image]
(Picture from https://electronic-studio.com/7425-dual-4-input-nor-with-strobe_1)
.

Comment: I think the diagram which shows the behavior as a compound AND/NOR gate to be much clearer, and would view likewise an alternative combining a 4-input OR and two-input NAND.  I wish compound gate symbols were more common, especially in MOS-based designs, since positive-logic AND and OR gates are expensive, but the cost of a compound AND+NOR or OR+NAND gate will be about the same as, or sometimes less than, a NAND or NOR with the same number of inputs.